# How to check whether two values exist in column [SQL Server]?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a BIT parameter that I am hoping to set to 1 if two values exist in a column of my temporary table.

I have had a look online and most people suggest using the CONTAINS function, however that requires me to change the settings in my environment which isn't an option. Elsewhere, I've seen LIKE mentioned, but when I've tried this its been no use as my aim is to make sure both values exist in the column but since LIKE is working on a row by row basis its not working as I am hoping. Here is what I have so far:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tempTable (Description nvarchar(100))

INSERT INTO tempTable
VALUES ('Word1'), ('Word2')

DECLARE @bValuesExist BIT

IF EXISTS(SELECT Description 
          FROM tempTable
          WHERE Description LIKE 'Word1'
          AND Description LIKE 'Word2')
SET @bValuesExist = 1

SELECT @bValuesExist
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7fbe1c/6

The results I'd hope for from the above code snippet is for the bValuesExist variable to be set to true since both values exist in the description column of tempTable. However, the code is currently checking whether the description column contains "Word1" and "Word2" on a row by row basis, how can I do this check so its on the whole column and not just the row?

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.  The question is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

`Description LIKE 'Word1' AND Description LIKE 'Word2'` can *never* be true, as a column's value (which is a scalar value) cannot be 2 different values at the same time. What you want here is a `HAVING` and a conditional aggregate:

```sql
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1
          FROM tempTable --This isn't a temporary table.
          HAVING COUNT(CASE Description WHEN 'Word1' THEN 1 END) > 0
             AND COUNT(CASE Description WHEN 'Word2' THEN 1 END) > 0)
    SELECT 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to check a list of values in the table.  One method uses aggregation:

```
SET @bValuesExist = (SELECT (CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT Description) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                     FROM tempTable tt
                     WHERE Description in ('Word1', 'Word2')
                    );
```

The `2` is the number of words.  The `DISTINCT` is to account for the possibility of duplicates in `tempTable`.

Note:  This does not require an `IF` in the code.

Comment: Thanks, this worked as hoped! I'm not sure how to mark your answer as correct since I'm new to this.